# What is these twostep, checkblocked about in this middleware?

Tags: laravel

I am 2-week-old to Laravel. I am using 5.8. I've planned to take the project from (https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth) for learning purpose. I use sublime to track the functionalities or keywords and to look how it's defined in src. I can't track some words anywhere in the file. Sorry in advance if this question was too dumb.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'activated', 'activity', 'twostep', 'checkblocked']], function () {

   //  Homepage Route - Redirect based on user role is in controller.
   Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'public.home',   'uses' => 'UserController@index']);

    // Show users profile - viewable by other users.
    Route::get('profile/{username}', [
     'as'   => '{username}',
    'uses' => 'ProfilesController@show',
    ]);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an array of middleware, hope you know about middlewares.
If not its just files where request goes first for chceking a particular conditions.

so now to your question ,  `'twostep', 'checkblocked'` are middleware where request goes to for a check before request to fullfill.

Hence, from variable name i can guess, These middleware is made for check , user on two-step verification(`twostep`) or not and second one, it checks, the user is blocked or not `'checkblocked'`,

If you wanna read these files code, you can go to kernal.php file inside `app/http` directory, and in this file, you can see an array named as `$routeMiddleware`, and track these files, inside middleware directory.

**Update**

Hence you did not get these files because user use these two packages for this.

for `twostep` user use [this](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel2step) package you can find this package inside composer.json file in project directory `"jeremykenedy/laravel2step": "^1.1",`

and now for second `checkblocked` , he also uses package for this.

You can also view this package inside composer.json file `"jeremykenedy/laravel-blocker": "^1.0",` here is the link of package [Package Link](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-blocker)

Comment: Bro.. I can't find these keywords even the class files in the Kernel path, e.g, CheckIsUserActivated::class, I checked most of them. I don't know what's this developer logic? where did he put em all?

Comment: you can find inside kernel.php file under $routeMiddleware[] , the line wiill be like  `'twostep'=>App\path-to-class`

Comment: File's link: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php    It may be the author's mistake to fail to write the logic. I checked the file and the Kernel variable already. But I can understand it should've been there but it's not. Thanks for the help. I upvote u.

Comment: See my updated answer, If you satisfied you can accept this answer too

Comment: I've  upvoted your answer. so he uses his own package. How composer adds his package. Can you give me a short answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194174/discussion-between-mithun-jack-and-karan-sadana).

Comment: Laracasts is great to learn about Laravel